# What application to select to open and download programs on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, 13.04, downloads, default-programs

I have tried downloading both Wine and VLC player, but it asks me to select an application to run the program installation. Not sure what to pick...shouldn't there be an application to automatically download something?

PS I'm a noob at this

Comment: what format of file you had downloaded?

Comment: as in, like, amd64 that kind of format? I'm just wondering what type of application to pick so I can download things

Comment: amd64 is not a fileformat,amd64 on the software name denotes this application belongs to `64 bit` operating system.So right click on the file and select the properties.Under the `basic` tab file Type was mentioned.what was that file type?

Answer (score 1):

You needn't run a program to install these. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

You could also open Ubuntu Software Center and look for and install both painlessly from there.

Comment: Hey, thank you chili555, looks like it is working :) I have one more question, if you'd be willing to let me ask you, You seem to know your way around ubuntu

Comment: @Hsskor You can always ask another question on the site.

Comment: @Hsskor I will be happy to help if I can. Unless it's very closely related to this, I agree that you should start a new question.